# OpenCL global worksize and offset question

Tags: opencl

Let's say the global work size is 32, and I set the offset as 1. Does this mean that `get_global_id(0)` would start from 1 and end at 31, making the effective global work size to 31 rather than 32?

If I want to retain the total global work size as 32, should I specify the global work size as 32+1 for when I set the offset to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the global work size as 32 and set the offset as 1, `get_global_id(0)` will start from 1 and end at 32. The global work size specifies the NDRange size and the offset does not change it.